# Python Desktop Application with HTML, CSS and JS

Tags: python, django, websocket, electron

I am building an application which is similar to stock market where the prices will change automatically on the front end without the request from the client ( no ajax ).
Something like websocket or server side events which pushes the latest price of the stock to the javascript. I can achieve this with django but I dont want to take it as web application instead need to run it as desktop application.

Many suggested electron for doing this but my application is already written in python and I have the following questions.

1. How to send stock price change to electron if am using python as a child process inside electron ?
2. Is there any way to implement server-side events or websockets in python code and make it communicate with whenever there is a change electron ?

Or is there any framework to do the above other than django to make desktop applications using front end technologies ?

Comment: If you want to use python with WebSockets you should consider tornado instead of django.

Comment: can tornado be packaged as desktop application ?

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller can bundle a webapp into an exe. The trick is adding the path to your venv in the .spec file datas. i.e.

```
             datas=[
             ('assets', 'assets'),
             ('c:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\python\\3.8.10\\x64\\lib\\site-packages', '.'),
             ],
```

So it will collect and bundle the server with the interpretter. Then you can just do

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed win.spec
```

to get your exe. with django, sanic, flask whatever.